# Actionscript 3 Event Target in XML Menu

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, event-handling, tween

I have a Image XML menu that works well, but with a litle problem with target in TweenMax. I will post only the code that is relevant to resolve the problem, I hope :D .

I have a **MC** in library, and inside I have 3 movie clips, **img_mc**, **bg_mc** (this is a background for text) and **title_mc** (inside this mc I have a textfield named **title-txt**).

I create a for loop for the **MC**, and I use e.currentTarget in my tween animations.

When I hovered the **title_mc** is suposed to scale the background, but because **bg_mc** are in back of the text, the hover don't works. I do not know how to target the **title_mc** for on MOUSE:OVER scale the **bg_mc**.

**Important Pieces of Code:**

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < my_total; i++)
   {
      //CREATE THE LOOP FOR MOVIE CLIP THAT I HAVE IN LIBRARY WITH THE CLASS "menu_item"
      var MC:MovieClip = new menu_item();
      MC.id = "i" + i;
      MC.label = my_menu[i]. @ LABEL;
      MC.name = "mc" + i;
```

**Animation Events:**

```
//ANIMATION EVENTS
MC.container_mc.bg_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hover_bg);
MC.container_mc.bg_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out_bg);

function hover_bg(e:MouseEvent)
{
   TweenLite.to(e.currentTarget,1,{scaleY:1.2,ease:Quad.easeInOut});
   TweenLite.to(e.currentTarget,1,{alpha:0.8});
}
function out_bg(e:MouseEvent)
{
   TweenLite.to(e.currentTarget,1,{scaleY:1,ease:Quad.easeInOut});
   TweenLite.to(e.currentTarget,1,{alpha:0.6});
}
```

This Last piece of code don't works because title_mc is over bg_mc.

If I put in event MC.container_mc.title_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out_bg); the Text will scale too, and I don't want this...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the [hitArea property](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Sprite.html#hitArea) of your MCs to there bg_mc clips. And set the MCs [mouseChildren property](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#mouseChildren) to false.

Comment: Ok, I understand you, I gonna try that. Thanks